# Calendar permissions in EXO – User added as Author can't see calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, office365, exchange

I executed this command in PowerShell:

> `Add-MailboxFolderPermission user1@example.com:\Calendar\test -User user2@example.com -AccessRights Author`

but user2 can't see this calendar. Can I do something so user2 can see
the "test" calendar in his Office 365 calendars?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need open the sub calendar in outlook profile, follow these below steps to do this:

- Go to File, Account Settings.
- Select your Exchange account and click Change
- Click More Settings
- On the Advanced Tab, click Add
- Type all or part of the name of the mailbox that was shared with you.
  Select the correct name if presented with a list of names.
- Click Ok and work your way out of the dialogs and return to Outlook.

Then check if this issue is been fixed.

A similar thread for your reference: [Accessing shared calendar that is NOT DEFAULT calendar.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/accessing-shared-calendar-that-is-not-default/f6255df3-66cc-4e98-9925-5200e5e584c8)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to first make the 'Top of Information Store' visible for user2:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user1@example.com:\ -User user2@example.com -AccessRights FolderVisible
```

then make user2 Author

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user1@example.com:\Calendar\test -User user2@example.com -AccessRights Author
```